# Object generation in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing

I want to generate some random objects in matlab. The objects which I want to produced are mostly circle and sinusoidal waves with a specific amplitude, width and radius. Is there any command and/or function that can do this? The location of circles and waves are random.

For example below you can see two sample objects:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after---sorry if I have misunderstood the question but I am generating a random number of points at which to make circles or sinusoids.

Circles:

```
N=randi(20);
x=rand(N,2);
plot(x(:,1),x(:,2),'.','MarkerSize',30)
```

And sinusoids:

```
amp=.1;
freq=10;
N=randi(20);
x=rand(N,2);
for i=1:N
    plot(x(i,1)-1:.01:x(i,1)+1,x(i,2)+amp*sin(freq*(x(i,1)-1:.01:x(i,1)+1)),'LineWidth',10)
    hold on
end
hold off
```

Hopefully the code is self-explanatory, but feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Good answer, especially the sinusoids! However, I suspect he wants image matrices, although it's not clear.  If that's needed you can make images out of the figure axes with `getframe`+`frame2im2`.

Comment: Thanks David. How I can control the radius of circle in the first code?

Comment: Change the `MarkerSize`, from 30 to a different size. The 30 is measured in points, but the circles are plotted at one sixth of that size. You could also try using empty circles, and filling them, so have `plot(x,y,'o','MarkerFaceColor','k','MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerSize',30)` and you can change the colours just like in normal Matlab plots.

Comment: @David: tnx again, is it possible to have the plot data as a matrix? Because I want to use those random sinusoidal waves as data (not as a plot). For example, I want to have it as a NxM matrix which its background be 0 and the waves be 1.

Comment: I think Chappjc's comment will do that, check out those commands.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the sinusoidal waves, but as far as the circles are concerned, you should be able to just pick random points in the image and use the [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) function. You would also need a circular structural element for this morphological operation. This can be achieved easily by using the [`strel`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/strel.html#bqkf9dn) command with the `'disk'` option; the required radius can be passed as a parameter here.